# I'm trying to make a get request to a Twitter API that eliminates clutter and in the url I have a variable and I can't get it to concatenate?

Tags: php, twitter

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");

$apikey="xxx";
$apisecret="xxx";
$accesstoken="xxx";
$accesssecret="xxx";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($apikey, $apisecret, $accesstoken, $accesssecret);


$response= 
$connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=10");

foreach ($response as $tweet) {

        $favorites=$tweet->favorite_count;

            if ($favorites>1) {

    $embed = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?id='.$tweet->id.'");

    print_r($embed->html);

                    }
    } 

?>
```

It works with a sample Tweet id# put in place of $tweet->id and I've tried a lot of different syntax to try and make this mini-app work. I'm new, and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the dots that you've got in there before and after `$tweet-id`. There's 2 ways that you could put the value in there in-line:

```
$embed = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?id='$tweet->id'");
```

(When surrounding your string with double quotes `"`, you can enter variables directly into it like any other text.

or

```
$embed = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?id='".$tweet->id."'");
```

(In this method, you make it explicitly obvious that you're adding a variable in there. Note that when using single quotes `'`, this method **must** be used.